# How to apply React-number-format to set of numbers in react

Tags: reactjs, number-formatting

This is my code snippet

```
<Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{data.country}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>Cases: {data.cases}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Text>Active: {data.active}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Text>Critical: {data.critical}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Text>Recovered: {data.recovered}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Text>Deaths: {data.deaths}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Text>Today's cases: {data.todayCases}</Card.Text>
            <Card.Text>Today's death: {data.todayDeaths}</Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
```

{data.country},{data.cases}....... all are numbers fetched from an API.I want to format the numbers by placing commas

```
<NumberFormat
                displayType={"text"}
                thousandSeparator={true}
                thousandsGroupStyle="lakh"
                value={data.cases}
              />
```

This formats the numbers according to Indian number system.
The code looks messed up if I use NumberFormat Tag for all the numbers ..Is there a common way of declaring the react-number-format so that it formats all the numbers???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using formatter to format numbers, I believe you should format data after you fetch it from API, and just display it, which will remove your hassle of using formatter at each and every place where you want to format data.

Comment: okay can u explain with an example on how to format numbers while fetching numbers from an API

Comment: Can you please share your json response from API and format in which you want it, I will share the code to format it.

Comment: Yes sure!  https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-swanson-4qu1q?file=/src/App.js I want the numbers to have commas as per the Indian number system

Comment: Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wave-4k65f, I hope you will get it now.

Comment: Thank you but i dont  think this will work fine for my code.Please check the link I hv the entire code.sorry for the inconvenience! https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-swanson-4qu1q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I understand, but you have to tweak your code logic of displaying data a bit, like first have data prepared as I have shown in the link and then try and display your page according to that data, rather than try and in corporate suggested logic in your current code, I hope you understand that.